# Individual distributions for Gradle multi-project

Tags: gradle, multi-project

I have a number of very similar (non-Java) projects that needs to generate Zip/Tar distribution. Generally each project simply has a `distributions` section that copies various files/directories and assembles the archive. I would like to extract common code to the separate "common" project but perform the build from the child project(s) so I can generate one archive based on the flavor I need. The common code is simply a directory(s) that need to be included into archive(s)

I probably will never run a build from the parent to generate multiple distributions.

I need to copy common files first and then add/overwrite files from the child project. I looked at examples from `samples/userguide/multiproject` and would like to use a flat structure. But these examples are pretty spartan so any examples would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look into this sample project https://github.com/fanick1/so-individual-distributions-for-gradle-multi-project

From what you have written in the question I assume that you are using the *distribution* plugin. The repository contains a multi-project consisting of one project (*commonProject*) with let's say common content:

```
commonProject/src/
  - commonFiles/
  - customFiles/customFile.txt
```

and two child projects (*projectA*, *projectB*) which are basically identical:

```
  project[A|B]/src/
    - customFiles/customFile.txt
    - files[A|B]/
```

You can run `gradlew distZip` which will create distribution zip files in each of the sub project in the `/build/distributions` folder. 
The child projects contain folder `customFiles` which is also located in the `commonProject`. It's content in the output zip file will be eventually overwritten by content in respective child projects if there is a file with same name.
Basically what this means is that file `/customFiles/customFile.txt` will be overwritten. Content in `/commonFiles` will be always copied into the child projects' distribution zip files.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks! I'm working through your code. It looks like in your example the master project nests children projects. One of the requirements is for project to use a flat structure so the "commonProject is also a master project. Can this be done?

Comment: Depending on meaning of _"...the requirements is for project to use a flat structure so the "commonProject is also a master project_" the needed modifications might vary. But the answer would probably be yes in any case. You can for example `includeFlat("projectA")` from `settings.gradle` within the `commonProject` and initiate `gradle distZip` from inside of the `commonProject`. Simply move all the gradle files into the `commonProject` and switch to `includeFlat` in the `settings.gradle`. 
If you want to build just one of the projects you can also run for example `gradlew :projectA:distZip`.

Comment: Thanks for your help and enjoy the bounty!

Comment: I did what you suggested to flatten the project and now I'm getting this: `* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':projectA'.
> Project with path ':commonProject' could not be found in project ':projectA'.`

Comment: Figured it out - instead of having `commonProjectContent project(path: ':commonProject', configuration: 'sharedContent')` in `dependencies` section it is actually `commonProjectContent project(path: ':', configuration: 'sharedContent')` because you simply refer to the root project as `:`